# NSWindow change width of sizing borders

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

I have custom borderless window with style set to these:

`NSWindowStyleMaskBorderless | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable`

and user is able to resize it by dragging its borders.

I need to find the way to change thickness of borders where user can start resizing.

On Windows I can do that by implementing `WM_NCHITTEST` message handler and return `HTLEFT`, `HTRIGHT`, etc. in corresponding areas.

Is there any way to do anything close in MacOS?

Comment: Something tells me you need these two methods: [`setContentBorderThickness:forEdge:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419541-setcontentborderthickness?language=objc) and [`autorecalculatesContentBorderThicknessForEdge:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419356-autorecalculatescontentborderthi?language=objc)

Comment: @hidefromkgb, setContentBorderThickness:forEdge: is about positioning of content NSView inside NSWindow. It has nothing with resizing tracking.

Comment: I'm not aware of any framework support for variable-sized resize drag regions. You could probably hack a solution by intercepting the window's `sendEvent:` message and, if it's a mouse down in the region you want, fake up a mouse down event that's closer to the edge and forward that to the window so it thinks the user is resizing. And yea, that's going to get ugly.

Comment: @JamesBucanek That's hackish of course. I suspect that it would be easier to remove NSWindowStyleMaskResizable flag and implement sizing loop  "manually" similar to `NSWindow performWindowDragWithEvent`. 

Another option is to get access to NSWindow tracking/cursor areas on borders  but there is no public API for that either AFAIK.

Strange actually that MacOS has nothing close to WM_HITTEST...